# Structured Data error for “Missing: homeLocation”

Tags: blogger, structured-data

Structured Data error for “Missing: homeLocation”
i have try setting all i could but still this error is still showing please how and where can i solve this issues 
someone should help me out pls
 and all my post has duplicate title and duplicate description please a guide line to fix it too. please help me.